# Method not declared in a inherited class

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a class named UnitDeckCard. It inherits from DeckCard, which inherits from TextureRect. My issue is that, in the UnitDeckCard, I'm trying to define an onready var with a node from the scene:

`onready var cost_label = $CostLabel`

But then I received an error `The method "get_node" isn't declared in the current class`

I thought that, since, by inheritance, UnitDeckCard inherits from a Control class (TextureRect class), get_node method would be available, as Control inherits from Node (get_node is a Node method). As I undestand, my case would be something like that:

UnitDeckCard < DeckCard < TextureRect < Control < CanvasItem < **Node** < Object.

Why can't I use get_node method in UnitDeckCard?

Comment: Your presumption that it should have access to `get_node` is correct. Why can't you use it? Don't know. I'd start by looking for typos. Also are there any other errors or warnings being reported? If nothing suffices, I'd try a minimal project. Edit: either in the process of making such minimal project you figure out the problem, or you have an issue to report.

Comment: The minimum project worked just fine. Then, I returned to the original project, and guess what? The error doesn't happen anymore...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I just needed to exit the project and open it again. Some sort of bug from Godot Engine, I guess.

The only notable thing I can say is that I wasn't using direct class names. UnitDeckCard was extending DeckCard using the script path `extends "res://deck_card_script_path.gd"`, then I started to use class_name and extending using the class name `extends DeckCard` instead of using the script path. Anyway, no idea what was throwing the error exactly since the inheritance should've worked in the first place.

Comment: I don't use that form extension by script path *at all*, however I know Godot stores what script is what class and extends what in project settings (that part not accesible from the UI). My guess is that it got out of sync somehow.